# External monitor on HDMI but no sound

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hdmi

This has been asked again but none of the answers apply because I've tried them all:

- My MacBook is a 2013 Retina Macbook Pro, so it supports audio through HDMI
- the HDMI cable is plugged directly into the HDMI port (no adapter)
- the monitor has speakers, and their volume is to 100% ([Asus PA248Q](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/PA248Q/))
- I've selected the HDMI audio output in the system settings
- I've tried with a different HDMI cable

But still no audio through the monitor's speakers. What am I missing?

FYI, the audio works fine in any other case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell from reading the [Specifications Page](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/PA248Q/specifications/), there are no speakers built into  this particular monitor.  There are however, two different audio outputs:  HDMI 1.3 and 3.5mm headphone/speaker jack

[image]

The easiest way to test this out is just get a cheap set of speakers or a headset with the 3.5mm jack and plug them in.  If it works, you know all is well with your setup - you just need speakers.

Comment: Oh my god thanks for reading that page correctly, it seems I wasn't able to do that. I assumed the jack port meant "audio input" (but it says right there "*output*"). I just bought jack cable today and tried it out: it doesn't work as an input. So, you are definitely right. In my defense the back of the screen looks a lot like speakers :)

Comment: Been there many times...no worries!

Answer (score 4):

If the screen is connected and switched on, you can select the speakers of your HDMI screen in System Preferences > Sound > Output.

Or if you have the audio volume button in your menubar, you could select it through OPTION + click on audio button. Then select the output device.

Comment: I said in the question "I've selected the HDMI audio output in the system settings"